# How do I prove, $3x^2+x\cdot z+z^2<0$ has no solution?

Tags: analysis

question is in the title. I basically have to show that the expression has no solution.

I can rewrite it as $z^2<-3x^2-x\cdot z$, but I don't feel like that is any helpful.

Thanks in advance.

EDIT:
x, z are real numbers.
Solution in regards to both variables.

Comment: Solution with regards to what variable or both variables ??

Comment: Forgot to add that, sry ^^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot prove it, because it is not true. For example, take $x=0$ and $z=i$ and the expression is satisfied.

However, to prove that there is no solution in the real numbers, here's a **hint**:

Try writing down $3x^2+xz+z^2$ as$$\frac{1}{2}(x+z)^2 + \text{something}$$

Comment: @Rebellos I know... which is why I gave the hint on how to solve the problem over the reals.

Answer (score 4):

Notice that the inequality can be rewritten as

$$\left(\frac{x}{2}+z\right)^2 < -\frac{11x^2}{4}.$$

Thus, there is no real solution.

Answer (score 1):

Let $f(x)=3x^2+xz+z^2=>f'(x)=6x+z=0=>x=-z/6=>$ if $x\ge-z/6$ then $f'(x)\ge0$ else if $x\le -z/6$ then $f'(x)\le0=>$
$$\min(f(x))=f(-z/6)=3z^2/36-z^2/6+z^2=z^2-z^2/12\ge0>f(x)\ge \min(f(x))$$